# Any good SQL shell programs?

Tags: software-recommendation, mysql, database

I want to practice SQL commands on Ubuntu. I would just like to play with different commands and keywords. Where can I find something that helps?

I don't want to install any server. I need a small app; something less than 20MB.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you want to play around with a lightweight SQL RDBMS, [SQLite](http://sqlite.org/) ([Ubuntu package](https://apps.ubuntu.com/cat/applications/sqlite3/)) is the standard choice. You have multiple options to use SQLite:

### Command-line

You can use the SQLite program directly from the command line by running

```
sqlite3 /some/database/file.sqlite
```

Type commands and press Enter (remember the trailing semicolon).

### GUI

Alternatively, you can install sqliteman, which provides a nice GUI browser for SQLite databases; you can also enter SQL code and execute it (displaying the results in the GUI):

[image: sqliteman screenshot]

Install via terminal:

```
sudo apt-get install sqliteman
```

Or:

[image]

## Caveat

Be aware that SQLite takes some unusual design decisions for an RDBMS:

- No client-server architecture
- Dynamically typed; SQLite does not enforce many constraints that other RDBMSs insist on. If you want to simulate MySQL-like typing, you have to explicitly add `CHECK` constraints.

Comment: Doest it need any remote connection? I want to work offline. Only need to play with commands.

Comment: Everything runs locally.

Answer (score 1):

Give a try [sqlline](https://github.com/julianhyde/sqlline) which is shell for issuing SQL to relational databases via JDBC.

There is a [project demos page with short demo videos](https://github.com/julianhyde/sqlline/wiki/Demos)

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/966645)

Comment: @guntbert since this is a software request and the answer does name the suggested program, I think it's OK. Serg, it would be great if you could expand this a little and explain things like how to install your suggestion or what makes it a good suggestion.